# how to use DO LOOP WITH PARTITION

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I have a Dataset with 3 columns - 'account', 'num_owners' and 'date' - ORDERED BY 'account' and then 'date'.
I want for each account, where there was a change in num_owners (up or down) to be flagged, using the SAS DO loop as such:

```
DATA test ;
    SET work.Owners_Change ;
    LENGTH change $20. ;
    RETAIN change ' ' ;
    ARRAY A[1] num_owners ;
    DO i=1 TO DIM(A) ;
        IF A[i+1] = A[i]
        THEN change = 'no change' ;
        IF A[i+1] > A[i]
        THEN change = 'Add' ;
        IF A[i+1] < A[i]
        THEN change = 'Subtract' ;
    END ;
RUN ;
```

It gives me an error: ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 32 column 6.

Comment: You defined an array with only one variable and the first place you use it you are trying to assign a value to the second (non-existent) variable in the array.

Comment: @Tom I am only using 1 variable in the array and the 'change'  variable was created with the RETAIN... I do not understand the issue.

Comment: How can you have an A[i+1]? A only has a single value so that is trying to access A[2]. In SAS arrays reference a variable in the same row, not different rows. I suspect you're expecting i to index across your rows which would be using _n_, not i. If you provide sample data and expected output someone may be able to help clarify.

Comment: What is the "WITH PARTITION" that you mentioned in the title of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have this line:

```
ARRAY A[1] num_owners ;
```

This creates an array with dimension 1. `A[1]` is a legal statement, and addresses `num_owners`; `A[2]` or higher, or `A[0]` or lower, would fail, as only one item is defined in the array.

Then you have this statement inside the loop:

```
        IF A[i+1] = A[i]
        THEN change = 'no change' ;
```

This says "If the second item in the A array is equal to the first item in the A array"; but that doesn't work since there is no second item.

---

Quick SAS array tutorial: unlike R or Python, an array in SAS is only a list of columns and has access to their values *on the current data row*, not anything else.  It's a programming method that allows you to do something to a group of variables, often a group where the variables have a meaningful order (but not always).

In SAS, you can *only* operate on the current row in nearly all contexts, with some very specific exceptions -  the way SAS mostly works is analogous to a loop in R or Python, for example, *always*, sort of like:

```
data a; 
  set b;
  if x = 1 then y = 5;
run;
```

in python might be something more like (psuedocode):

```
for b_row in b.rows():
  if b_row[x] = 1 then b_row[y] = 5;
```

But just like in Python you couldn't take `b_row[x+1]` and expect that would get you the next row of `b` (you'd have to approach it differently), you can't get access to the next row in SAS by saying `A[i+1]`, either.

The best choice here is either to do a merge where you merge the next row to the current row:

```
data want;
  merge sashelp.class sashelp.class(firstobs=2 keep=age rename=age=age_next);
  if age = age_next then sameage=1;
run;
```

Or to use the `lag` function, and primarily operate on the "next" row rather than the "previous" row.

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class;
  if lag(age) = age then sameage=1;
run;
```

This is different - note where `sameage` ends up - but you can make it work the same way by sorting the input dataset *in reverse order* and then you're getting the same result.

```
    proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
      by descending name;
    run;
    
    data want;
      set class;
      if lag(age) = age then sameage=1;
    run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually thought that sas array works the same as in python!

Comment: A common misconception.  SAS is really closer to SQL than any of the other statistical languages - it is REALLY good at doing the same thing to every row in a table, but its not optimized for doing things where you need information from multiple rows.  There are a bunch of ways to do it, though - just not as obvious as a vector-based language.

Comment: BY group processing with the NOTSORTED option could make this simpler by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to use LAG() and not an array to test if the current value of NUM_OWNERS is different than the previous value.

```
data test ;
  set work.Owners_Change ;
  length change $20. ;
  if num_owners = lag(num_owners) then change = 'no change' ;
  if num_owners > lag(num_owners) then change = 'Add' ;
  if num_owners < lag(num_owners) then change = 'Subtract' ;
run;
```

Be careful with LAG(), do not call it conditionally or the chain of values it uses will be interrupted.  Notice how I did not include `else` before the secondary `if` statements.  You could also just store the lagged value into another variable and test that.

```
data test ;
  set work.Owners_Change ;
  length change $20. ;
  num_owners_lagged=lag(num_owners);
  if num_owners = num_owners_lagged then change = 'no change' ;
  else if num_owners > num_owners_lagged  then change = 'Add' ;
  else change = 'Subtract' ;
run;
```

Comment: Exactly! I eventually used LAG(). Is ARRAY not valid in this case?

Comment: An ARRAY will not allow you to reference values from different observations.  It just allows to you do the same operations across multiple variables and avoid having to create "wallpaper" code.